# DateTime Conversion to Date

Tags: ssis

I wanted to convert DateTime data which will be pulled from source, to Date format only or I want to retrieve only Date with no time. How is it to be done  here ? Also how is to be done for converting the Datetime data for a customised format while pulling from the source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripping the time was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844029/how-do-i-strip-the-date-off-of-a-datetime-string-in-sql-ssis). Could you possibly use a similar method?

Also...

Refer BOL --> Convert

print convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)

print convert(varchar(10),DateTimeCol,101)

[courtesy of Srinika](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=60088)