# How can I get the date of the day 20 minutes earlier in SSIS reliably?

Tags: sql-server, date, variables, datetime, ssis

I'm working on a project in SSIS that takes cost and assigns it to a certain week.  The weeks are identified by the date of the next Sunday.  I run the package every 20 minutes.  So at 12:00:47-ish on 10/12/2014, I want to obtain the week of "10/12/2014", delete all records for that week, then repopulate with the final data for that week.  To get the prior day, I subtract 20 minutes.  20 minutes later, the week should be "10/19/2014" in order to start populating cost for the new week.

I'm using this formula, partially obtained from this page:
[How do I strip the date off of a datetime string in SQL SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844029/how-do-i-strip-the-date-off-of-a-datetime-string-in-sql-ssis)

```
TheDayThatIsTwentyMinutesPrior = (DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)DATEADD("minute",-20,GETDATE())
```

It seems to work correctly in the editor.  Another variable calculates the number of days until Sunday:

```
DATEPART( "dw", @[User::TheDayThatIsTwentyMinutesPrior] ) == 1 ? 0 : 8 - DATEPART( "dw", @[User::TheDayThatIsTwentyMinutesPrior] )
```

Another calculates the week:

```
DATEADD( "day", @[User::DaysTillSunday] , @[User::TheDayThatIsTwentyMinutesPrior]  )
```

Then I run a DELETE statement (Execute SQL Task) using that variable:

```
"DELETE FROM WeekCost WHERE Week = '" +  (DT_WSTR, 100)  @[User::Week] + "'"
```

I also have an UPDATE statement that calculates the delta between the weeks.

The first week this ran, the prior week was deleted on Monday.  I added some logging to discover what code was being executed and the results are confusing.

```
DateCreated           SQL
10/12 23:40:54.113    DELETE FROM WeekCost WHERE Week = '10/12/2014'
10/12 23:40:55.433    UPDATE ... '10/12/2014'
10/13 00:00:47.753    DELETE FROM WeekCost WHERE Week = '10/12/2014'
10/13 00:00:48.647    UPDATE ... '10/12/2014'
10/13 00:20:54.363    DELETE FROM WeekCost WHERE Week = '10/12/2014'
10/13 00:20:55.287    UPDATE ... '10/19/2014'
10/13 00:40:49.490    DELETE FROM WeekCost WHERE Week = '10/19/2014'
10/13 00:40:50.363    UPDATE ... '10/19/2014'
1am is correct
doesn't run again till 5am
5am entries are both 10/19
10/13 05:21:33.427    DELETE FROM WeekCost WHERE Week = '10/12/2014'
10/13 05:21:35.240    UPDATE ... '10/19/2014'
...all correct...
10/13 07:20:45.870    DELETE FROM WeekCost WHERE Week = '10/12/2014'
10/13 07:20:47.323    UPDATE ... '10/19/2014'
...
9am has the DELETE wrong
...
10/13 09:40:48.587    DELETE FROM WeekCost WHERE Week = '10/12/2014'
10/13 09:40:49.757    UPDATE ... '10/12/2014'     !!!
10am has the DELETE wrong, but the UPDATE is correct
...
3pm has the DELETE wrong
```

DateCreated comes from a SQL default of GETDATE().

I figure either I'm doing the minute subtraction wrong or SSIS is caching the date variables and I'm missing a setting to have them update.  I can't determine any pattern to the date calculations and it seems to work correctly except for Mon. after midnight till sometime in the afternoon.  Most of it works correctly, in the few cases where it's wrong on the DELETE, it's correct on the UPDATE except for one instance.

I did find this question, but no answer, unfortunately.  I am running 2008, however.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501501/ssis-2005-date-variables-not-evaluating

Update:
I tried passing the date variable as a parameter instead of using a variable as the SQL Source, but a significant number are still showing as 10/19 after it should have switched to 10/26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was running SQL Server 2008 SP1.  A fix is listed on Microsoft's site that addresses this version.  [FIX: The variables of an SSIS 2008, SSIS 2008 R2 or SSIS 2005 package are evaluated incorrectly when you run the package in parallel.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2448991)  The article lists two conditions that apply:

- These variables are evaluated by using a hierarchy of expressions. These expressions use other variables and some base variables. The default values of the base variables have been set.
- You run the package in parallel.

SP4 for SQL Server 2008 was installed and the variables now evaluate reliably.