# SSIS Adds Date to time field upon exporting to excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to run an SSIS program to take some logging data and export it into Excel for later use with a BI tool. The data has 3 time fields, a start time, finish time, and run time. They appear to be correct coming out of my script component. As it looks perfect when I use the dataviewer tool

However when I go into Excel I get this type of format.

[On Run Time column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYmM1.png)

I am not sure what is causing this or how to fix it. The only thing that I was able to notice was a property in the sources advanced editor set the column data type to date.

[The Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLBFO.png)

But every time I try to change it to type DB_TIME (same type as coming out of script) it just switches back to the date data type.

Is there a way to prevent the adding of this date? It makes the use of the BI tool impossible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the result into an nvarchar before making exports (via query)? In this way excel sees information as a string with the format you want

Comment: i have not. can you explain how that is done?

Comment: use CONVERT(NVARCHAR,starttime,103) as starttime (eg. DD/MM/YYYYY) in your query, you can find more info about format [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx), in this way the data are exported to excel as strings with the same format. then Excel will not recognize the fields as date, but as string

Comment: .NET doesn't have a Time type. Changing the destination type is *not* going to convert System.DateTime to DB_TIME or automagically cut the date value. You need to cast to DT_DBTIME

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I strip the date off of a datetime string in SQL SSIS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844029/how-do-i-strip-the-date-off-of-a-datetime-string-in-sql-ssis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It had something to do with the Excel connection manager auto recognizing that field as a date time field, and therefor it exported it in that format. This change was happening in the connection between the final component and the destination, so casting did not work as it happened after that.

I simply changed the xls file to a csv and used the flat file manager and that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

That seems like odd behavior to me, but try adding a Data Conversion Transformation to your package. This should force whatever type of data you want, either string or time.

Comment: I have tried the Data Conversion component without success. However when I tried to convert to string it gave me a 'The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data'  error, so possibly I need to figure that out and try getting a string.

Comment: What conversion did you try? Your script component returns either a DateTime object or  a string, .NET doesn't have a Time type yet. Did you try casting to `DT_DBTIME` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried to cast to date time, and I have tried to return just the time out of the script component. as a dbtime with the c# timespan datatype. Neither achieved the goal

Comment: or DT_DBTIME in ssis

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

> DT_WSTR(1252)

to cast the time using Data Conversion Transformation?